# Calculating sum of consecutive powers of a number multiplied by a consecutive number

Tags: summation, exponentiation

There is a serie that i want to calculate for a competitive programing question.
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \left(81i \cdot 10^{i-1} - 10^{i-1} + 1\right) $$
Most of it is easy but at the end i end up with:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n 10^{i-1} \cdot i $$

So it abstracts to: $$\sum_{i=1}^n P^i \cdot i : P\in ℤ_{>1}$$
I can implement an recursive function, but i get time limit for large numbers. How can i simplify this to a simple function, is it possible?

Comment: Hint: $\frac{d}{dx}x^{m}=mx^{m-1}$ and geometric sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

From

$$1+2\cdot10+3\cdot 10^2+4\cdot 10^3+\cdots n\cdot 10^{n-1}$$ subtract $10$ times this number and simplify the equal powers of $10$. This leads you to the solution.

Comment: There's a typo: $n\cdot 10^{n-1}$

Comment: No Jamal that is not a typo, it refers second sum i wrote. Thanks Yves that was what I looking for. I ended up with $$ \frac {10^n \cdot n - \frac{10^n - 1} {9}} { 9} $$

Answer (score 0):

You can use calculus;
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{n} P^i\cdot i &= P\sum_{i=1}^{n} P^{i-1}\cdot i\\
&= P\sum_{i=1}^{n} P^{i-1}\cdot i\\
&= P\frac{\mathbb d}{\mathbb dP}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} P^i\right)\\
&= P\frac{\mathbb d}{\mathbb dP}\left(P\cdot \frac{P^n-1}{P-1}\right)
\end{align}  
$$
I think you can take it from here.